# Select the same column from same table with different WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have two tables:

1st table: `PATIENT` with columns:

```
ID number(PK), LastName varchar2, FirstName varchar2
```

and sample data:

```
ID  LastName    FirstName
-------------------------
1    Jobs       Tom
2    Norks      Jack
3    Loonie     Peter
```

2nd table: `PAYMENTS` with columns:

```
ID number(PK), PATIENT_ID number (FK Patient.ID), PRICE number, 
EXTRA_PAYMENT number (takes only 0 or -1)
```

and sample data:

```
ID   PATIENT_ID  PRICE   EXTRA_PAYMENT 
----------------------------------------
1       1        50€        0
2       1        20€        0
3       3        40€        0
4       1        30€        0
5       2        70€        0
6       3        25€        0
7       2        5€        -1
8       3        25€        0
9       2        10€       -1
10      2        50€        0
```

I want to create a query to return these 3 columns:

```
PATIENT             PRICE       EXTRA_PRICE
--------------------------------------------
Tom Jobs            100€            0€
Jack Norks          120€            15€
Peter Loonie        90€             0€
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation after joining the tables:

```
select p.firstname || ' ' || p.lastname as patient,
       sum(pm.price * pm.extra_price) as price,
       sum(pm.price * (1 - pm.extra_price)) as extra
from patients p left join
     payments pm
     on p.id = pm.patient_id
group by p.id, p.firstname || ' ' || p.lastname;
```

EDIT:

For the *changed* question, you can use `case`:

```
select p.firstname || ' ' || p.lastname as patient,
       sum(case when pm.extra_price = 0 then pm.price end) as price,
       sum(case when pm.extra_price = -1 then pm.price end) as extra
from patients p left join
     payments pm
     on p.id = pm.patient_id
group by p.id, p.firstname || ' ' || p.lastname;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff and thanks for your response. the payments.extra price column is a true/false column. So if this column is true (-1) then the amount of a payment.price field goes to  PRICE column in my query, but if payments.extra_price value is false (0) then the amount of payments.price field goes to Extra_Price query column. I don't want to multiply my two fields (Price and extra price) in the Payments table.